# Como usar CSS dentro de un jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Lo que deseo es que este jQuery{

```
<script type="text/javascript" class="navegacion_header">
    jQuery(function(){
    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
        if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
            jQuery('#logo-img img')
               $( "#logo-img img" ).addClass( “logo_cambio” );
                .attr('src','<?php  echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/images/logo-tva2.png');
        }
        if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() < 200) {
            jQuery('#logo-img img')
                .css({'width':'113px','height':'168px', 'margin-top':'0',
          '-webkit-transition':'all 0.5s ease',
          '-moz-transition':'all 0.5s ease',
          '-ms-transition':'all 0.5s ease',
          '-o-transition':'all 0.5s ease',
          'transition':'all 0.5s ease'
                  })    
                .attr('src','<?php  echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/images/logo-tva2.png');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Pueda detectar en el archivo CSS, esta clase:

```
.logo_cambio{
  width:51px;
  height:73px; 
  margin-top:-7.5%;
}
```

Ya intente añadiendole al jQuery este método `$( "p" ).addClass( “logo_cambio” );`

Pero no me funciona.

Comment: Hay errores de sintaxis por lo que veo con un primer vistazo en el jquery. ` $( "#logo-img img" ).addClass( “logo_cambio” );
                .attr('src','<?php  echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/images/logo-tva2.png');` esto directamente no hace nada, ya que el `.attr` está suelto. Te recomiendo que primero limpies el código

Answer (score 1):

Buenas creo que con esto te podrá servir de guía, lo he hecho con colores, tendrás que cambiarlo y ponerlo con imágenes, te he dejado comentada la parte de imágenes

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
    //var ruta1 = "./img1.png";
    //var ruta2 = "./img2.png";
    
    $(window).scroll(function(){

      var posicionScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

      if (posicionScroll > 200){
        
        $("#logo-img img").removeClass("logoInicial");
      $("#logo-img img").addClass("logoCambio");
        
        //$('img').prop("src",ruta1);

      }else{
        
        $("#logo-img img").removeClass("logoCambio");
      $("#logo-img img").addClass("logoInicial");
        
        //$('img').prop("src",ruta2);
          
      }
     
    });

});
```

```css
html{
  background-color:gray;
}

#logo-img{
    height: 1200px;
    background-color:green;
    
}

#logo-img img{
  position: fixed;
}

.logoInicial{
  width:113px;
  height:168px;
  background-color: orange; 
  margin-top:0%;
  transition:all 0.5s ease;
}

.logoCambio{
  width:51px;
  height:73px;
  background-color: red; 
  margin-top:-7.5%;
  transition:all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="logo-img">
 <img src="" class="logoInicial">
  <!-- <img src="./img1.png" class="logoInicial"> -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```